# How to handle Spring JPA repository SQL error when occur?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa

In my project I am using Sring JPA repositories concept to interact with database.
Now repository has many inbuild CRUD functions like Repository.save().. which saves the entity

Now during saves sometimes I get the sql error like below and save operation fails:
**SQL Error**:

```
2012-06-28 10:28:43,217 [WARN] [pool-1-thread-1] [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22001
2012-06-28 10:28:43,217 [ERROR] [pool-1-thread-1] [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - Data truncation: Data too long for column '<Column Name>' at row 1
```

My concern is **how to handle these kind on error in java code**, because I cannot see this method throwing some exception which I could handle upon these kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you probably business classes or POJOs that check if the length is not too big you can find on the hibernate forums that hibernate is logging this.

See for example [Persist object error : Data too long for column (in MySql)](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1012052) and [Data truncation: Data too long for column](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=961616).

It is not Spring Data related at all.